# Generalization of the hairy ball theorem.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

The hairy ball theorem of states that there is no nonvanishing continuous tangent vector field on even dimensional n-spheres.

Can the hairy ball theorem be strengthened to say that there is no continuous tangent vector bundle of dimension 1 on even dimensional n-spheres?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by a "continuous tangent vector bundle of dimension 1"?  If you mean a rank 1 vector bundle, then every manifold has one:  $M\times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I mean a rank 1 vector bundle in which the line assigned to the point s in the sphere lives in the tangent space of the point.

Answer (score 5):

I'm interpreting "continuous tangent vector bundle of dimension 1" to mean a rank $1$ subbundle of $TS^{2n}$, i.e., a $1-$dimensional distribution.

In this case, we have the following result (I do not know who first proved it).

> If $E\subseteq TS^{2n}$ is a rank $k$ subbundle, then either $k=0$ or $k=2n$.  In other words, $TS^{2n}$ has no non-trivial subbundles.

Proof:  Suppose $E\subseteq TS^{2n}$ is a subbundle.  Since $TS^{2n}$ admits a fiberwise metric, $E$ has a complement $E^\bot$ in the sense that $E\oplus E^\bot \cong TS^{2n}$.

By the Whitney sum formula for the [Euler Class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_class), we know $e(TS^{2n}) = e(E)\cup e(E^\bot)$.  Identifying the Euler class with the Euler characteristic, we have $e(TS^{2n}) = 2\in H^{2n}(S^{2n})$, so $e(E)\cup e(E^\bot) = 2$.  Since $H^k(S^{2n}) = 0$ unless $k = 0$ or $k=2n$, the result follows.

Comment: It will be terrific if you could give a reference.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this exact result is found in Milnor and Stasheff's characteristic classes book.  I'll check tomorrow (if I remember)

Comment: This argument doesn't work. A 1-dimensional vector bundle is trivial if and only if it is orientable, so the only interesting case is when the 1-dimensional subbundle is non-orientable. In this case the Euler class is undefined so such an argument can never work.

Comment: @PVAL-inactive:  I see what you're saying, but as every vector bundle over $S^{2n}$ is orientable (since $S^{2n}$ is simply connected), I wouldn't say this argument doesn't work.  But I would wholeheartedly agree that it is overkill and that your observation is the best way of proving it.

Comment: A great attack by @PVAL-inactive and a brilliant  defense by Jason. This kind of duel contributes to what makes our site so wonderful! (+1 to both of them, of course)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach which doesn't use characteristic classes.

> Suppose $M$ has no connected double cover.  Then it has a non-vanishing vector field iff $TM$ admits a rank $1$ sub-bundle.

The hypothesis on $M$ is satisfied iff $\pi_1(M)$ has no subgroup of index $2$.  In particular, this applies to all simply connected manifolds.

**Proof**:  One direction doesn't depend on properties of $M$ at all: if $M$ admits a non-vanishing vector field $V$, then $\operatorname{span}\{V\}$ is a rank $1$ sub-bundle of $TM$.

Now we prove the more fun direction.  Suppose $L\subseteq TM$ is a rank $1$ sub-bundle.  Choose a background Riemannian metric on $M$ so that we may talk about lengths of vectors.  Let $\tilde{M} = \{(p,v)\in L: |v| = 1\}$.

Then $\pi:\tilde{M}\rightarrow M$ given by $\pi(p,v) = p$ is a $2$-fold cover.  By hypothesis, $M$ doesn't admit any connected $2$-fold covers, so $\tilde{M}$ must be disconnected.  Writing $\tilde{M} = M_1\coprod M_2$, it follows that $\pi:M_i\rightarrow M$ is $1$-sheeted, so is a diffeomorphism for each choice of $i$.

In fact, then the inverse $\pi^{-1}:M\rightarrow M_1\subseteq L\subseteq TM$ is a non-vanishing vector field on $M$.

Answer (score 1):

A classic result of Frank Adams on vector fields on spheres gives the full story on generalisations of the hairy ball theorem and answers your question in the affirmative. See http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970213 (the statement of the result is visible on the first page, even if you don't have full access to the paper).

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not see why the theorem you mention gives an affirmative answer to my question.

Comment: The theorem says that the number of linearly independent vector fields on an $n$-sphere is $\rho(n+1)-1$, where $\rho(x)$ is the Radon-Hurwitz number of $x$ (see the paper by Adams and the papers it refers to or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_on_spheres). $\rho(n+1) = 1$ when $n$ is even, giving us no non-zero vector fields at all on even-dimensional spheres.

Comment: @Rob:  I don't think Pedro is interested in tangent vectors as much as the 1-d subspace they span.  It seems a priori possible that one could potentially pick a field of $1$-d subspaces in $TS^{2n}$ but couldn't consistently choose a nonzero vector from each subspace.

Comment: For example, $S^{5}$ admits a field of $4$-planes, despite the fact that the maximum number of linearly independent vector fields it supports is $1$:  Given a nonvanishing vector field $V$, let $E(p) = V(p)^\bot \subseteq T_p S^{5}$ (where $\bot$ is computed relative to, say, the standard Riemannian metric on $S^5$).